# populate fullcalender with a startdate and endate list

Tags: javascript, events, jakarta-ee, fullcalendar

Good morning , I'am putting a fullcalender on jsf web and i want to use my data from database instead of static data but i tried it with no success

I did a function that returns a list of holiday and i dont know how to put the startDate and endDate in the event of the fullcalendar

`

## Service

```
@Override
public List<Holiday> Getholiday() {
    Query query = em.createQuery("select p from Holiday p");
    return query.getResultList(); 

}
```

## Bean

```
 @ManagedBean(name="lista")
 @SessionScoped
 public class AffichageHoliday implements Serializable {

@EJB
private HolidaysServiceLocal holocal ;
private Holiday holy ;
public String data = "1";


public String getData() {
    return data;
}

public void setData(String data) {
    this.data = data;
}

private List<Holiday> pls ;

  @PostConstruct
    public void init() {

      pls= holocal.Getholiday();


    }

  public List<Holiday> doGetAllHolidays()
    {
         pls = holocal.Getholiday();
        return pls;
    }



  public String loading(){
        return "Editholiday.xhtml";
    }  

  public String updateholidaymethode()
    {
        holocal.update(holy);
        return  "/AffichageHolidays.xhtml?faces-redirect=true";
    }



public Holiday getHoly() {
    return holy;
}

public void setHoly(Holiday holy) {
    this.holy = holy;
}

public List<Holiday> getPls() {
    return pls;
}

public void setPls(List<Holiday> pls) {
    this.pls = pls;
}
```

## Holiday Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name="Holidays")
@NamedQuery(name="Holiday.findAll", query="SELECT h FROM Holiday h")
public class Holiday implements Serializable {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Column(name="HolidayId")
private int holidayId;

@Column(name="EndDate")
private Date endDate;




@Column(name="StartDate")
private Date startDate;

//bi-directional many-to-one association to User
@ManyToOne
@JoinColumn(name="ResourceIdFK")
private User user;
```

## jsf fullcalender

```
$(document).ready(function() {

$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
  header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay,listWeek'
  },
  defaultDate: '2018-03-12',
  navLinks: true, // can click day/week names to navigate views
  editable: true,
  eventLimit: true, // allow "more" link when too many events
  events: [


    {
      title: 'All Day Event',
      start: '2018-03-01',
    },
    {
      title: 'Long Event',
      start: '2018-03-07',
      end: '2018-03-10'
    },
    {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: '2018-03-09T16:00:00'
    },
    {
      id: 999,
      title: 'Repeating Event',
      start: '2018-03-16T16:00:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Conference',
      start: '2018-03-11',
      end: '2018-03-13'
    },
    {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: '2018-03-12T10:30:00',
      end: '2018-03-12T12:30:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Lunch',
      start: '2018-03-12T12:00:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Meeting',
      start: '2018-03-12T14:30:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Happy Hour',
      start: '2018-03-12T17:30:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Dinner',
      start: '2018-03-12T20:00:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Birthday Party',
      start: '2018-03-13T07:00:00'
    },
    {
      title: 'Click for Google',
      url: 'http://google.com/',
      start: '2018-03-28'
    }
  ]
});
```

});

Comment: Are you using any jsf framework like Primefaces or similar for the calendar component? Where this fullCalendar comes from?

Comment: i donwloaded fullcalender.js

Comment: Did you mean https://fullcalendar.io/? I googled fullcalender.js and nothing appears.